# Spring Batch : Job only to fire service

Tags: java, spring, quartz-scheduler, spring-batch

I currently have multiple Quartz pollers that check a multiple flags in the database and fire a service if flags are true and I also have one spring batch project reading files, then calling a service to update the information accordingly.

What i am wondering is if it is possible to get the spring batch application to only call a service very 5 minutes (dont check for any information just call a service which will handle all the business logic) so that i can remove the Quartz jobs from my application all my jobs are in one place (spring batch project)?

If so can any point me in the right direction on how to do this as i cannot find anything online to just set up a spring batch job just to fire a service?

Comment: i don't think spring batch can to it automatically, you need to trigger batch after each 5 mins,either by some schedular or simple infinite for loop with thread sleeping for 5 mins

Comment: i could set up a Quartz job on the Spring Batch application which i could trigger every 5 minutes. My question on this really would be is it possible to get this Quarts job only to fire an individual service... do you always have to have a reader, processsor and writer in spring batch?

Comment: you can directly call the service in Quartz job, you don't need spring batch or any reader writer for that.

Comment: well that is what i have at the moment but i want all jobs to be running from one place (spring batch application) so if any changes need to be made this can be done seperate from the other applications?

Comment: now i am confused, could you give some example.Do you need spring batch or not ?

Comment: no i dont need it to do anything with Batches, just need it to fire off a Service every so often

Comment: so you can use what i have told  you in my answer. Simple call your service from executeInternal method. That executeInternam method will be called automatically based on your cron entry.

Comment: i will give this a go so and update my question if i get it going with the below process

Comment: ok. sure, if it works for your then accept my answer. If you got stucked with this approach, i will like to help you out

Answer (score 0):

You can simply schedule a Quartz job and call your service from executeInternal method of your schedular class. You will not be able to autowire your service directly in schedular class, so you need to set it using jobDataas Map.

```
   <bean class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean">

    <property name="triggers">
        <list>
            <bean id="cronTriggerCache"
                class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.CronTriggerBean">
                <property name="jobDetail" ref="exampleJob" />
                <property name="cronExpression" value="your cron expression" />
            </bean>
</list>
</bean>    
 <bean name="exampleJob"       class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.JobDetailFactoryBean">
<property name="jobClass" value="example.ExampleJob"/>
<property name="jobDataAsMap">
    <map>
        <entry key="myService" ref="myService"/>
    </map>
</property>
</bean>

 package example;

 public class ExampleJob extends QuartzJobBean {

private myService myService;

/**
 * have getter setter for you service
 * 
 */


protected void executeInternal(JobExecutionContext ctx) throws JobExecutionException {
    // do the actual work
     //call your service method here
}
```

}